# Importing a project into Visual Studio. Why so many errors?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, import

This isn't really coding specific, but we currently have a project that is live and working fine. I am tasked with making a few changes to it. I imported the ALL files of the project to Visual Studio 2010. I can't get any work done, because of all the errors!

Do you have any suggestions for me? The project doesn't have a source file, so I created a project and made one myself.

I tried another version of Visual Studio, and the errors continue. How in the world is this project even working?

Also, I have no way to speak with the creator.

Thanks for the help!

Josh

Comment: Are you missing external references? What type of error are you getting? What type of project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the specific errors you're running into, I'm guessing that you are hitting one of two scenarios:

- The source code references .NET assemblies that you do not have installed on your development machine.  The only way to correct this is to get your hands on a copy of those assemblies to install them.  The assembly names should be in the error messages, which would give you a good starting point to look from.
- It's also possible that differences in the .NET framework versions that it was originally developed in and what you are trying to use now are accounting for a large number of errors.  If the errors specifically reference the version number, this is most likely what you're experiencing.  If this is the case, there are ways you can upgrade the individual file versions that your program references, but I honestly haven't done that in about 8 years, so I'm drawing a blank at the moment as to how to do it.

Comment: I did see .NET assembly errors which I corrected. But a lot of the errors were with the writing of the code, in which I fixed my doing them a different way. There were 205 errors to be exact. I'll look into the .Net framework...that is probably the key to this all. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Visual Studio was set for .NET 3.5 Framework. Had to change it to 4.0, and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand ? 
you have a "project" (what kind of project?) that you want to start working with with VS2010 ?

You add the files to a new VS2010 project and start building it and many errors occur ?

What kind of errors ? Language (C++/C#) errors ? missing include missing ? missing libraries ?

Can you show a some of the errors you get ?

Comment: It is a web project in vb. It also has a lot of java in it. All files were imported, so I don't have anything missing. It was just general code errors. Weird. I think it has to do with the framework as Nate mentioned. Thanks for your feedback!